# Does spring boot come in to picture only while creating the project?

Tags: spring-boot

I've been learning spring boot for a while and as per my understanding, we use spring boot only to create the project along with dependencies and embedded servers. It doesn't have much of a role while working on the project or after the project is created.

I mean, if i were to work on an enterprise application for a company, chances are that, there is already a project created using springboot and I don't have to really use spring boot anywhere while working on that project.

Is my understanding correct?

I've tired googling, but did not find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. You may still need to use the following spring-boot features after creating a project :

- [Externalise the application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config)
- [Test the application using testing utilities and annotations provided by spring-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing)
- Use its [auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-auto-configuration) feature to quickly configure if you need to enhance your application with other library/framework afterwards.
- Use its [developer tool](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools) to make you have a better Dev experience (e.g  automatic restart the app when code changes , hot-reload static content etc.)
- Use [Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) to monitor your application health and gather metrics.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, if i were to work on an enterprise application for a company, chances are that, there is already a project created using springboot and I don't have to really use spring boot anywhere while working on that project.

I think you can say pretty much the same about any framework out there. I can't agree with this statement in general.

Every framework (including spring boot) provides a set of features that you may opt to use or not to use in your project.

So yes, for each **existing** microservice you'll have a `@SpringBootApplication` class.
Also probably set of configurations / practices how to work with configurations.
You'll already have also spring beans on existing project.

However software constantly evolves (otherwise it doesn't make sense to hire programmers, you know).

So when you (as a new employee) need to create a new micro service then, congratulations, you're using Spring boot features.

Other day-to-day tasks include (just a couple of example out of the head):

- Create Integration Tests (`@SpringBootTest`)
- Define new configuration Properties
- Use Actuator
- Use Metrics + define new metrics
- Reconfigure Logging
- Writing Liquidbase/Flyway migrations
- Integrate new set of beans (Configurations)
- Use Autoconfigurations

and so on and so forth.

If you want to really understand what you're doing while implementing these tasks you should know how do relevant features provided by spring boot work.